# How Client / Server RPC works with global variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am quite new to Unity and i can't find any logical answer to the behaviour i am seeing.

I have written a basic script such as :

```
public class PlayerPosition : NetworkBehaviour
{

    private Dictionary<string, int> testDict = new();

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void HitServerRpc(string key, int value)
    {
        RefreshClientRpc(key, value);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void RefreshClientRpc(string key, int value)
    {
        testDict[key] = value;
        foreach (var item in testDict)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Item in current dict {item}");
            }
    }

   // Other logical code that calls only HitServerRpc().

}
```

I am using this script on my player `Prefab` in a client / host situation.
I have one client and one host (server + client) for the test and the question.

My question is :  Why `testDict` has only one key and one value when at least 2 different keys and value were added through 2 different RPC calls, one from each client ?

The log `Item in current dict` is shown only once even if the `HitServerRpc()` was called on two different clients :

- `HitServerRpc("user1", 3)`
- `HitServerRpc("user2", 4)`

All clients should have `testDict` equaled to : `{{"user1", 3}, {"user2", 4}}`

PS : Weirdest thing, i have tried to move the `testDict` in a static class and update it internally inside the static class instead of the class handling the RPC calls, it now has the correct values on the host but still not on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All clients should have testDict equaled to : `{{"user1", 3}, {"user2", 4}}`

I see why you think that, but no! Each of those calls accordig to you comes from a different client -> and thus from/to a different instance of your `PlayerPosition`.

Let's say as in your description you have two players `user1` and `user2`.

Each of these is calling `HitServerRpc` on **their** respective local authority instance of `PlayerPosition`. Which then gets relayed as a ClientRPC to the other connected clients but still only to **their** respective instance.

Trying to visualize this

```
user 1 Device              Server       user 2 Device

user 1 (local auth) ---->  user 1 ----> user1
user 2              <----  user 2 <---- user 2 (local auth)
```

The result would be that the respective dictionaries are indeed synced, however, `PlayPosition` belonging to user 1 would only know the key `user1` and accordingly the other instance only have the `user2` key.

So I think in your use case actually rather using a **static** would make sense. There is no need though to put it into a different class. You could use

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> testDict = new();
```

so all the local instances of `PlayerPosition` use the same dictionary instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I actually get it now ! However despite the static variable, this is still not working on the client, only on the host :/ Do you know why ?

Comment: Can you add more logs and see if they actually come through on your devices? As you say yourself the log should appear on both client devices two times (make sure collapse is disabled in the console) ... I would add logs to the top of the methods themselves like `Debug.Log(nameof(HitServerRpc), this);` and accordingly `Debug.Log(nameof(RefreshClientRpc), this);` .. the additional `this` allows you to click once on the logged message and it will highlight the according instance in the hierarchy

Comment: Yes ! actually i have logged everything, on the client i only get 1 item all the time and on the host i am getting 2 items. I have built on 2 unity editor (with 2 computers) and editor + android physical device the outcome remains the same (logs too)... I saw your edit let me try these !